# Parsing datetime using JSONConverter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, datetime

I would like to use `JsonConverter` to convert the `DateTime` value response from database to following format. `1 Jan 2011, 1:30 AM`. However I do not know how this could be done. The default datetime format retrieve is `01/01/2011 01:30:00` (from what I have debug). I am stuck here.

Additional Note: The time retrieve is in UTC format, and I need the datetime retrieve to be local time of user.

```
public class DateTimeConverter : JsonConverter
{
   public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        ...
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        ...
    }
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        ...
    }
}

public class NewModel
{
    [JsonProperty, JsonConverter(typeof(DateTimeConverter))]
    public DateTime RegiterUTCDateTime { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Do you want to convert the database value into C#? Or do you want to convert the C# into JSON?

Comment: Additionally, you should understand that a `DateTime` doesn't have a format - and the format used by calling `ToString` will depend on your culture. Oh, and UTC isn't really a format, it's a time zone. Additionally, it's not clear how you're fetching the `DateTime` from the database, but that shouldn't rely on string parsing at all. At the moment, this question is really unclear.

Comment: @DavidG: I'd guess he's getting a `DateTime` from his ORM, and he wants that to be serialized to a string in JSON using the format that he describes.

Comment: @DavidG striplingWarrior has just help me explain it

Comment: Then I would recommend that if your dates are all in UTC time zone - keep them that way! Use the standard JSON format for date time values and let the client determine how they display it.

Comment: @DavidG can't it be done in server side. The requirement is that the date should be culture independent and time zone dependent, so i thought it would be easier to be done through server side.

Comment: If you want culture and time zone independence, then why convert it to a string like `1 Jan 2011, 1:30 AM` which is neither?